# How do I correct the following error when trying to install `matplotlib` : don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

#### There are a lot of missing executables, the installer also says it is trying to compile ForTran code (people still write *ForTran* !??)

```
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable DF
Could not locate executable efl
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
Could not locate executable g95
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
Could not locate executable flang
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
```

#### My system:

```
         Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18362) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 10/31/12 20:41:07 Ver: 36.02 (type: BIOS)
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
                   Memory: 4096MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 4064MB RAM
                Page File: 14314MB used, 2036MB available
```

#### The full error message is:

```
C:\Users\Sam>C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install matplotlib --user
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/d1/7b12cd79c791348cb0c78ce6e7d16bd72992f13c9f1e8e43d2725a6d8adf/matplotlib-3.1.1.tar.gz (37.8MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 37.8MB 6.4MB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sam\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-60hly6r_\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sam\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-60hly6r_\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60hly6r_\matplotlib\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60hly6r_\matplotlib\
    Complete output (205 lines):
    ================================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.1.1]
          python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC
                      v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]]
        platform: yes [win32]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
             agg: yes [installing]
           tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl/Tk]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
            dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable DF
    Could not locate executable efl
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py:418: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 163, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 26, in run
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 142, in run
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in build_sources
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 286, in build_library_sources
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 369, in generate_sources
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 241, in try_link
        self._check_compiler()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 54, in _check_compiler
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
        self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
        self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 443, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 443, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vhwz71px\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60hly6r_\matplotlib\setup.py", line 262, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Stack overflow says, "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So, I'm forced to write this little bit of text at the end here; sorry.

Comment: Best don't try to install matplotlib on python 3.8 for now. Or be prepared to go through all the compilation problems step by step.